# Independence between sums of $Z_k$

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, independence

Let's assume you are faced with the following random variables
$$ X_i = \sum_{k}\alpha_{i,k}Z_k + \epsilon_i$$
where $Z_k,\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d. standard normal random variables and $\alpha_{i,k} >0$ are non-null coefficients. You can think of the $Z_k$ as common risk factors and the $\epsilon_i$ as the idiosyncratic risk factors driving $X_i$. Assume you also know
$$Y = \sum_k\beta_kZ_k$$
where $\beta_k >0$ are non-null coefficients. Hence, I know that we can re-express the random variables $X_i$ as a function of the variable $Y$ and a "residual part" of the $Z_k$. Precisely:
\begin{eqnarray}
    X_i &=& \sum_{k}\alpha_{i,k}Z_k + \epsilon_i \nonumber \\
    &=& \gamma(Y-Y) + \sum_{k}\alpha_{i,k}Z_k + \epsilon_i \nonumber \\
    &=& \gamma Y-\gamma\sum_k\beta_kZ_k + \sum_{k}\alpha_{i,k}Z_k + \epsilon_i \nonumber \\
    &=& \gamma Y + \sum_{k} \left(\alpha_{i,k} - \gamma\beta_k\right) Z_k  + \epsilon_i \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
This development is used in research papers like the one of [Pykhtin's](https://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/e9c944cf9ab30ac9c12577b4001e0342/$FILE/Pykhtin-Multi-fractor%20adjustment.pdf). However, I struggle to understand why in this final expression
$$ X_i = \gamma Y + \sum_{k} \left(\alpha_{i,k} - \gamma\beta_k\right) Z_k  + \epsilon_i $$
does the $Y$ is now independent from the "residual part" of the $Z_k$ (the second term, the sum over the $k$), when the $Y$ is actually a function of the $Z_k$, or am I missing something?

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be operating with the misconception that functions of the same RVs cannot be independent. The simplest example is given by $Y_1=Z_1-Z_2$ and $Y_2=Z_1+Z_2$ where the $Z_i$ are *iid* Normal variables: because the $Y_i$ are linear combinations of the $Z_i$ they are bivariate normal, whence independence is equivalent to zero covariance.  You can easily confirm the covariance of the $Y_i$ is zero.  Therefore, as I suggested in your [post on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643156), just compute the covariances. (That implies an unstated condition on $\gamma.$)

Comment: @Whuber: Indeed ! The "trick" relied in the use the normal distribution properties, where $0$ covariance implies independence (and vice-versa), very elegant.